# svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for ssh+svn / E204900 Permission denied

Tags: svn

I'm trying to setup a new subversion server. It's installed and I've imported a repository from the old server. I can check this repository out to my desktop. When I change a file and try to commit it, I get the following error in Eclipse SVN:

```
svn: E204900: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E204900: Can't open file '/path/to/repositories/testproject123/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

On the (Amazon Linux) server, SVN 1.8.13 is installed. The (Ubuntu 14.04) desktop client is version 1.8.8. Modules and schemes are the same.

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.8.13 (r1667537)
   compiled Aug 25 2015, 01:06:14 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2014 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.7
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

I tried to do a checkout using the commandline, and that resulted in the following error:

```
$ svn co ssh+svn://john@domain.test/path/to/repo
svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'ssh+svn://john@domain.test/path/to/repo
```

This command doesn't work on the old server as well. I do have ssh access to both servers using the same username as for svn.

The svn repository files are owned by `apache:apache`.

**How can I commit files to this repository? How can I checkout using the commandline?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two (unrelated) problems

1. Correct protocol for "SVN over SSH" is `svn+ssh://`
2. Repository files (all tree) must be RW for SSH-user, under which you connected to server

Comment: Thanks. I had to add myself to the apache group, and set write rights for the group on the folders and files.